# How to resume animation from the stop point?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I have `ViewController()` and `Circle.swift`.

In my `Circle.swift` I have all animation code and from the `ViewController` I just call it.

So, in Circle file I have:

```
func commonSetup() {
    ...

    fillingLayer.strokeStart = start
    anim.fromValue = start
    anim.toValue = end
    fillingLayer.strokeEnd = end

    fillingLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "circleAnim")
}
```

where I set `start = 0.0` and `end = 0.55` above the `class Circle: UIView {`.

In my `ViewController` I have a button, on click on it I call:

```
func pressed() {
    start = 0.55
    end = 0.9

    Circle().commonSetup()
}
```

but it doesn't work. My animation doesn't resume. How can I fix it? I want to at first load from 0 to 0.55, and after button clicked - from 0.55 to 0.9.

What I do not see in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change value of `fromValue`, `toValue` and `strokeStart` as often as you do:

```
func commonSetup() {
  ...

  fillingLayer.strokeStart = 0;
  anim.fromValue = START_VALUE //value expressed in points
  anim.toValue = END_VALUE //value expressed in points
  fillingLayer.strokeEnd = end

  fillingLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "circleAnim")
}
```

You should set values of `fromValue`, `toValue` and `strokeStart` properties and doesn't change them. You can control your animation only by changing `strokeEnd` property.

Comment: when animating stroke, the start and end values are from 0.0-1.0, not points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're creating a new instance of circle when you say `Circle().commonSetup()` You need to call `commonSetup` on the instance of circle that you've created before.

So it might look more like this. In your view controller you'd have a variable for the circle.

```
let progressCircle = Circle()
```

Then, in your pressed function:

```
func pressed() {
    start = 0.55
    end = 0.9
    progressCircle.commonSetup()
}
```

If you wanted to use it as a class function instead of an instance function (which probably would be incorrect for something like this), you would need to define the `commonSetup` function with the `class` keyword, as follows:

```
class func commonSetup() {
    //code
}
```

Then, you would use it like: `Circle.commonSetup()`. Note the lack of parenthesis on `Circle`. This is because you're running a class function, not initializing a new instance of the class. However... making this a class function would be weird to do in your case, since your function is really working on instances and not a class-level action.

I usually make a habit of using the proper keys for my animations as well. So yours would say: `fillingLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "strokeEnd")`